# Plot x and y tensors

Tags: tensorflow.js

Given this two tensors
`x=tf.tensor([1,2,3,4])` and `y=tf.tensor([4,6,7,8])`
I would like to plot `y=f(x)`. Are there any visualisation tools as tensorboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visualisation tools like chartjs, d3.js, ...

```js
(async function train(){
const x = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const y = tf.tensor([2, 4, 6, 8]);
const data1 = await x.data()
const data2 = await y.data()
 new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          label: "x",
          data: data1,
          pointBackgroundColor: "red",
          borderColor: "red"
        }, {
          label: "y",
          data: data2,
          pointBackgroundColor: "green",
          borderColor: "green"
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        showLines: false,
        legend: {
          labels: {
            usePointStyle: true
          }
        }
      }
    });
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.12.4/tf.js"> </script>
    <!-- Load chart.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```